# Multiple dex files error when Migrating to the New Places SDK Client

Tags: android

I am adopting the new update of google Places sdk in my app. I uses the version below. But I have problem with it. I don't have any clue if what is the cause of the issue. I don't know what is FinalizableReferenceQueue mentioned in the error.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
}
```

There is no error upon building the project. The error only will show when I run the project. I'm using Android Studio.

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue;
```

Comment: Can you please post a list of the other dependencies in your gradle file?

Comment: Hi @amuramoto, I finally found the cause of the issue. Thanks. Below is my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error, commenting one dependency at a time, I finally found the issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.com.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 201811141
    versionName "2018.11.14.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' 
implementation files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
// App's dependencies, including test
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation project(':aFileChooser')
}

//This are all the libraries that I commented to fixed the issue.
//implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')//this will give mutidex error
//implementation files('libs/droid-fu-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
//implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0'
//implementation 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6' //this will give error if use
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, I'll offer a little more explanation...

The underlying cause is that the project is pre-compiling DroidFu as a JAR and including it as a dependency, which packages a few Guava classes without relabeling the package path, leading to version conflicts with Guava dependencies in the the Places SDK lib.

Wanted to note this since it could be an issue in other projects that rely on Guava.